# Replace NA values per group with concatenated values from the same column

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I wish to achieve the following:

For each `Group`, when the `ID` column is NA, then fill the corresponding NA value in `Name` with the concatenation of the other values of `Name` **while ignoring other NA values in `Name`**

My data frame looks as follows:

```
x <- data.frame(Group = c("A","A","A","A","B","B"),ID = c(1,2,3,NA,NA,5),Name = c("Bob","Jane",NA,NA,NA,"Tim"))
```

[image]

This is what I wish to achieve:

```
y <- data.frame(Group = c("A","A","A","A","B","B"),ID = c(1,2,3,NA,NA,5),Name = c("Bob","Jane",NA,"Bob Jane","Tim","Tim"))
```

[image]

If there's a way to achieve this in the tidyverse I would be very grateful for any pointers.

I've tried the following but it doesn't find the object 'Name'

```
 x %>% group_by(Group) %>% replace_na(list(Name = paste(unique(.Name))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use a conditional expression with `replace`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
x %>% 
   group_by(Group) %>%
   mutate(Name = replace(Name, is.na(ID), str_c(Name[!is.na(Name)], 
          collapse = ' '))) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  Group    ID Name    
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>   
1 A         1 Bob     
2 A         2 Jane    
3 A         3 <NA>    
4 A        NA Bob Jane
5 B        NA Tim     
6 B         5 Tim
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% group_by(Group) %>% 
   mutate(Name = case_when(is.na(ID) ~ paste(Name[!is.na(Name)], collapse = ' '), TRUE ~ Name))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   Group [2]
  Group    ID Name    
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>   
1 A         1 Bob     
2 A         2 Jane    
3 A         3 NA      
4 A        NA Bob Jane
5 B        NA Tim     
6 B         5 Tim
```